# Data is not inserted as per schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I had defined mongoose schema and i tried to insert data into mongodb.But it is not inserted as per defined schema

```
export const EmpSchema: mongoose.Schema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  empNo: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  skill: {
    type: [String],
    required: true
  },
  address: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
}, {
  _id: false,
  versionKey: false,
  retainKeyOrder: true
});
```

It is getting stored like **Array elements** as last field.like

```
name
empno
address
skill
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    export const EmpSchema: mongoose.Schema = new Schema({
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      empNo: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      skill: {
        type: [String],
        required: true
      },
      address: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    }, {
      _id: false,
      versionKey: false,
      retainKeyOrder: true
    });

YOUR SCHEMA DEFINATION IS CORRECT PLEASE CHECK THE CONTROLLER PART WHERE YOU PUT THE INSERT QUERY . THERE MATTERS A INSERTION ORDER
```

Comment: when i try like this its showing error (property assignment required)

Comment: whats the problem u are getting when you use yours above define a schema. As I am not getting your question clearly( It is getting stored like Array elements as last field.like)

Comment: as per my schema it should store data into db in the order 
{
name:"aaa", 
empno:"111",
skill:"aaaa,ssss",
address:"qqq"
}

Comment: YOUR SCHEMA DEFINATION IS CORRECT PLEASE CHECK THE CONTROLLER PART WHERE YOU PUT THE INSERT QUERY . THERE MATTERS A INSERTION ORDER

Comment: but it is getting stored as  { name:"aaa", empno:"111",  address:"qqq", skill:"aaaa,ssss"}

Comment: check the order in your  insert query

Comment: const Employee:mongoose.Model<mongoose.Document> = mongoose.model('employee', EmpSchema); 
let employee:mongoose.Document = new Employee(req.body);

Comment: my req.body is same as schema order, but when i print  the employee there itself the order gets changed

Comment: make a object {name: req.body.name,empNo:req.body.empNo,skill:req.body.skill,address:req.body.address:req} then insert it